# newsletter subscription field not showing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber, field

[image]

my newsletter subscription field is not showing on the main page but it is showing in on the other pages. the top screen shot is of the home page and the other one is from the products page. Please guide be on this problem. I'm using magento 2.3.5

Comment: I think there is a CSS issue. Check by inspect element.

Comment: could you please guide me how can i fix this

Comment: or should I recompile the whole site ?

Comment: its say i must have 20 reputation to chat their

Comment: Oh let share your site url so i can check and guide you. Once you share then delete your comment.

Comment: .block.newsletter input { display: block: }
add this css code in your custom css file

Comment: but on the other pages its still none and yet its displaying the field

Comment: No. On other pages it's display:inline-block;

Comment: i'm kinda new at magento so could you guide me where can i find the custom css file

Comment: You can get details from here https://store.magenest.com/blog/custom-css-file/

Comment: in this section    //  Newsletter subscription
    .block.newsletter {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;

        .form.subscribe {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }

Comment: Add one more line in it.
.block.newsletter input { display: block: }

Comment: should i add "input" also ?

Comment: and after this should i recompile it ?

Comment: No only css line which i gave you. Then flush cache.